# How to send class parameters to controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, parameter-passing

my class;

```
public class Disciplines
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

my controller;

```
public void test (Disciplines discipline)
{

}
```

and using ajax i want to send parameters to test controller.

my javascript is ;

```
    var disciplines = {Id:1, name:"white"};
            $.ajax({

                type: "POST",
                url: "test",
                data: { disciplines:disciplines },
                dataType: "Json",
                success: function (response) {
                },
                beforeSend: function () {


   showIndicator();
            },
            error: onFailure,

        });
```

when i debug it controllers parameters always null.
How can I do it succesfuly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: have you tried `data:  disciplines,`?

Comment: You must have the same object parameter name as "Id ","Name "

Comment: In your ajax, you are writing `dataType: "Json"` but you are expecting `Disciplines`, a custom object. You will have to receive JSON and parse it to your object manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because the model binder will be looking for `id` and `name` properties in the request, not `disciplines`. Try this:

```
var disciplines = {
    id: 1, 
    name: "white"
};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "test",
    data: disciplines,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
    },
    beforeSend: function () {
        showIndicator();
    },
    error: onFailure,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be

```
 var disciplines = {"Id":1, "Name":"white"};

$.ajax({

                type: "POST",
                url: "test",
                data: { disciplines:disciplines },
                dataType: "Json",
                success: function (response) {
                },
                beforeSend: function () {


   showIndicator();
            },
            error: onFailure,

        });
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public void test (Disciplines discipline)
{

}
```

Must have same **parameter names** as in **class**

Comment: I would assume it's because wrapping the parameter names in the object in quotes will make no difference. The model binder will be looking for `Id` and `Name` properties, not `disciplines`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Their is a difference in `Name` and `name`.That is not binding to paramter name.

Comment: Given that the OP is working in ASP.Net MVC (given the code structure and his previous questions) that makes no difference - the model binder is case-insensitive.